# Accessible HTML Form input types - "submit" vs "image"

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there any real difference to screen reader users (or any users really) whether i use "image" rather than "submit" as the type attribute for my form submission button?

eg:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

vs

```
<input type="image" src="myButtonImage.jpg" value="Submit!" alt="Submit!" />
```

Comment: In my frustrated experience, there appears to be a difference in what is returned to the server in a POST request: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, they're essentially the same.

See: [Using 'button' and images for submit](http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/6-button-submit.html).  Just make sure to always give the image submit alt text.