# Unable to use image button as a directory to another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I somehow managed to add an iamge button into my web application. I'm trying to "activate" this image button as my button for my home page. For example, when i  clicked it, it will direct me to the home page.

This is my initial image button code.

```
<input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg"  />
```

This is after i added the common html code to activate the imagebutton as my home page

```
<input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg" a href="PoliceHomePage" />
```

Unfortunately after adding the ahref i received this error.

```
Validation(HTML5): Attribute 'href' is not a valid attribute of element 'input'.
```

I research and attempt this and the error persists.

and they return to me error like this

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

So what is the right code?

***UPDATE***

I finally managed to get it

```
<a href="PoliceHomePage.aspx"><img src="image/logo.jpg" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="PoliceHomePage"><input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg" /></a>
```

A is different tag, href is param of A.

Comment: doesn't work :( i can see the loading icon of the page but it is not being directed to the home page. It remains at the same page.

Comment: Deepsy is correct. what is `PoliceHomePage`? either it should be `.aspx` or `.htm` with some extension rt.? @user2316009

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the link as a value to the NavigateUrl property
example:

```
ImageButton1.ImageUrl="~/img.png"
ImageButton1.NavigateUrl="~/default.aspx"
```

give it a try

Comment: I'm dynamically using html5 code to add on the image button. Hence i do not have any NavigateUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a "img" tag inside a "a" tag

```
<a href="PoliceHomePage"><img src="image/logo.jpg" alt="img"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please on your page ?

pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="false"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using the type="image" wrong. Like what the error says, "Validation(HTML5): Attribute 'href' is not a valid attribute of element 'input'.".
See this question: [Input Type image submit form value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value)

You can either use an ImageButton's PostBackUrl (Gets or sets the URL of the page to post to from the current page when the ImageButton control is clicked),

or this:

```
<a href="/">
    <img id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg" />
</a>
```

Just customize the redirect url and the image's src.