# How can I fill a submit button with an image?

Tags: html, css, image, button

so I have a submit button with this code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="icon" value=" "/>
</form>
```

an in the CSS I have:

```css
.icon{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url(http://www.lcda.fr/pneu-expo/images/drapeau_rond_gb-on.png);
    height:20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-position:center;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

But the problem is that the image ( that have h:40px and w:40px)  does not shrink to fit the 20px button... Do you guys have any solution for this??
(I rather not use javascript if possible)

EDIT:
Currently working. I just delete history, cash and it works... ty

Comment: Seriously, I would *never* use Java for something like this. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Best solution IMO is to store the image with a size of 20px/20px; this way the browser does not need to it when rendering the page.

Comment: Which browser? because for me it works like you expect it to. It shrinks

Comment: `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: I meant javacript, sorry...
The problem is that I cant change the Image :/

Comment: background-size: cover; could do the trick because it fills the whole button. BUT. would it shrink? Never tested that.

Comment: Agree with Panky, see http://jsfiddle.net/kPbqb/

Comment: I tried your code in a JS fiddle and it looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/quHwh/ (I added the green border to see the input better). It's possible you have conflicting CSS somewhere.

Comment: Update the question, since its not clear.

Comment: I am testing it in firefox..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value

Comment: why didn't u selected any answer ?

Answer (score 3):

try this : -

```
background-size:20px 20px;
```

Comment: Please note that background-size isn't supported in IE 8 and earlier

Comment: For any problem for the IE 8 and later versions see this page http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/19221/background-size-and-ie8/p1

Answer (score 3):

Use an [image submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) instead, and shrink the element to the desired dimensions using CSS.

```
<input name="submit" type="image" class="icon"
style="width: 20px; height: 20px"
src="http://www.lcda.fr/pneu-expo/images/drapeau_rond_gb-on.png"
alt="Send" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the button, Updating the image:

```
document.body.onclick=function(e){
    debugger;
    var bid=document.getElementById('bid');
    bid.style.backgroundImage="url('http://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo4w.png')";;
}
```

js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kPbqb/2/).

Comment: Click on the body (next to the button) to change the image.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in css file:

```
display:block;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap a span to submit button and style it.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/H5dmd/2/

## HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <span class="icon">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" "/>
    </span>
</form>
```

## CSS

```
input[type=submit]{
    background:transparent;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:none;
    padding:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.icon{
    float:left;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url(http://www.lcda.fr/pneu-expo/images/drapeau_rond_gb-on.png);
    height:20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-position:center;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size: 100%;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use input of type image, it exists for this purpose exactly: submit button showing an image. As a bonus you'll also get the coordinates where the user clicked.

Example:

```
<input name="mysubmit" type="image" src="http://www.lcda.fr/pneu-expo/images/drapeau_rond_gb-on.png" />
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/6HhhN/1/).

Only one downside: in the server side code handling the form, you'll have to check if "mysubmit.x" and/or "mysubmit.y" are not empty to know if you got anything sent which is less intuitive than just checking "mysubmit".

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple options here :

## Change saving

Save your image to 20x20, and whoops, problem gone.

## Use CSS3

CSS3 introduces a new feature that is [backgroud-size](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/)

Just put that in your CSS :

```
background-size: 20px 20px;
```

But it won't be compatible with old browsers.

## Use JavaScript [Bad style]

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" name="myform">
    <a onclick="javascript:document.forms['myform'].submit ();" ><img src="myimage.png" onclick="submit();" /></a>
</form>
```