# Firefox triggers click event on hidden input of type image, but Chrome does not

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

[Here is a JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4kP/3/) that illustrates the problem.

Inside a form, I have an input of type `image` inside a hidden `div`. That hidden `div` has a `click` event that triggers an alert (attached with jQuery). I also have a basic text input inside the same form.

On Chrome, when I press Enter in the text input, nothing happens. On Firefox, the alert is triggered, meaning that Firefox triggers a click event on the hidden div.

**Which of Chrome and Firefox implements the correct behavior, and how to work around this issue on the browser that does not?**

Comment: I am not sure that there is a "correct" behaviour here. But as pressing <Enter> isn't, in my opinion, clicking I would put my money on Chrome. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hitting enter in a single text input in a form submits the form.  It does this by triggering a click event in some cases.

In Firefox, it seems to trigger a click event on the default submit control of the form, whatever that control is (and an image input can be a default submit control).

In Chrome it does the same, but only if the default submit control has a CSS box (which is why the `display:none` matters in Chrome).

Per the spec at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#implicit-submission there should be no dependency on CSS here: the synthetic click activation steps are run no matter what, so Chrome's behavior is definitely wrong.

As for Firefox, the question is whether an image input is a "submit button".  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29 says that in fact it is, so the Firefox behavior is the correct one in this case.

In terms of workarounds, one possible option is to explicitly set `form=""` on the image input if you don't want it submitting the form, which will make it not associated with the form and hence not the default submit button for it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Boris.

Comment: After two years! I found this to be very useful. Thank you Boris!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with an input of type image.  From what I have been able to find via Google (including this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value)), an image input is supposed to function like a submit button.  If it is supposed to function like a submit button then I would assume that pressing enter on a form would submit it (hence the click event in FF).  However, should it do so when the button is hidden?  While I have not had time to look into that, it appears to be a browser implementation choice.

As far as a work-around, it depends on what you are trying to do (and if an input of type image is really the right way to go).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Note that the problem is the same with an input of type `submit` instead of `image`, as you can see in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5j4kP/4/. I agree that this seems to be implementation-dependent.