# HTML form does not submit data

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have one page with a simple post form

```
<form name="click" action="UserOrders.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total ?>">
     <input type="image" src="/Templates/images/UpdateButton.png" name="submit">
</form>
```

and the only thing I want to check is if it submits.. In the other page "UserOrders.php" I just wrote

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
    echo $_SESSION['ID'];
}
```

It seems to me irregular that it doesn't work and I would like another set of eyes to check it out.
(if i put the `echo $_SESSION['ID']` outside the brackets, it works.)

Answer (score 0):

> An `input type="image"` only defines that image as the submit button and not as an input that can carry over a value to the server. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935484/250259)

An alternative way to see if the form was submitted is to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    // submitted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer.  You are not actually putting any information to the form and therefore there is nothing for the new form to react to.  $_POST['submit"] is looking for data that was sent and not for the method of sending.

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual submit button. You need a

```
<form action="UsersOrders.php" method="POST">
    <input type="whatever you want" name="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now if you go into UsersOrders.php and do what you did before:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    echo $_POST['input'];
}
```

You will actually get some input.