# how to submit input with image type

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

I can submit input with type "submit" but once I changed it to "image" it doesn't submit.

**Works with submit:**

```
<FORM ACTION="balance.php" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="addBal" type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

**Doesn't work with image:**

```
<FORM ACTION="balance.php" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="addBal" src="pics/add.png" type="image"/>
    </form>
```

**Output end (balance.php):**

```
if(isset($_POST['addBal'])) {
    echo 'TESTER';
}
```

**I've made a typo: but the problem still remains. Type submit works, and image doesn't**

Comment: "pics/add.png" is not a valid type. What do you think "type" means, out of curiosity?

Comment: that's a typo, I'm sorry. I mean image, and forgot to add src. I just typed it off by heart.

Comment: Your code works fine, only `if(isset($_POST['addBal'])) {` will not validate because the input type image doesn't actually send anything to the server.

Comment: I don't get it. Why have a type 'image' if it cannot validate?

Comment: You can submit a form with input type image. But unlike an actual submit button, it doesn't send a value to the server. Where with a submit button the name `addBal` will be send to the server with an empty value, the image won't send anything. So you need another value to validate if the form has been submitted.

Comment: I see... So you can send a form of values, but not a single value itself... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this example:

```
<button type="submit" name="addBal" style="padding: 0; border: none;"><img src="monkeydluffy.png" /></button>
```

It can serve the same purpose of submitting. As for additional information, you can check out this discussion regarding your concern.

> [Input Type image submit form value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for type `image`:

```
<input name="addBal" type="image" src="pics/add.png" alt="Submit" />
```

Comment: I had that initially(forgive typo), but somehow submit echoes and image doesnt

Comment: Check the image source.