# How to assign value to image

Tags: html, image, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to assign a value to image?

My problem is I have a drag and drop html

I have 10 pictures

From the 10 available pictures, I have to drag and drop maximum 3 pictures to the slots

How do I know the name of the 3 pictures I have put in the slots?

any help would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding ID to the images, for example:

<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="..." id="image1">

Comment: how do I get the image id that I put in the slots?

Comment: Im not really sure what you intend to do, so I am guessing here. You might have to use some jquery, have a look at this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-attributes.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value    This code seems to do what you might be looking for:You could use a radio button/checkbox and set it to hide the button in css and then give it a label with an image.

input[type="radio"] {display: none}
input[type="radio"] + label span {display: block}
Then on the page:

<input type="radio" name="emotion" id="mysubmitradio" />
        <label for="mysubmitradio"><img src="images/f.jpg" />
    <span>if you need it</span></label>
And then set it to submit using javascript:

document.forms["myform"].submit();