# Create .png image from value sent from client [node]

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a highchart client side. What I need to do is to get a png of that chart and store it server side.

Currently, I have produced the highchart, got the SVG and converted it to a PNG (shown below):

```
function saveThumbnail(graph_name, chart) {
    canvg(document.getElementById(graph_name + '_thumb'), chart.getSVG());
    var chart_Canvas = document.getElementById(graph_name + '_thumb');
    var chart_Img = chart_Canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    $('#graph_name').val(graph_name);
    $('#graph_png').val(chart_Img);
    $('#imageForm').submit();
}
```

This is my **`#imageForm`**:

```
<form action="/overview" id="imageForm" method="post">
    <input id="graph_name" name="graph_name" type="hidden" value=""/>
    <input id="graph_png" name="graph_png" type="hidden" value=""/>
</form>
```

So I have set the value of the PNG to that `input` which was what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value) and I have posted that value back to the server.

**Server side:**

In the function below, I am trying to create/write to a file with the name of the graph PNG sent back and trying to write that PNG into that file.

```
function createFiles(graphName, graphPNG, callback) {
    fs.writeFile(graphDir + graphName + ".png", graphPNG, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File was saved!');
        }
    });
    callback(body);
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

**Note:** Cannot have the highcharts server side. It was a decision made earlier and we are unable to go back.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or is the file just containing the wrong data?  What is the result of your current attempts?

Comment: @ebyrob if I have my code like it is above, the serves spits out a 500 error. The file has been created but shows the error `Image not loaded` when I click to view it

Comment: Open the file with text and hex editors.  Sounds like you need to convert what you're uploading into binary and save it as a proper PNG file.

Comment: @ebyrob opened with Atom and small icon displays. Open with notepad and it's in Ascii. How best to convert it to binary?

Comment: @ebyrob I have attempted using `atob()` to go straight to PNG from base64 but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify data type in fs.writeFile:

`fs.writeFile(graphDir+graphName + ".png", graphPNG, 'binary', function(err){`

binary or base64 switch your data ;)

Comment: Tried both and still no luck :(

Comment: If you console.log(graphPNG) what had you ?

Comment: It is a very long base64 encoding..basics of: `data:image/png;base64,`... _and then continues with loads of Ascii_

Comment: `try fs.writeFile(graphDir+graphName + ".png", graphPNG, 'base64', function(err){`