# How to get <input type="image"> in servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have to send the image statically as an input from HTML page to servlet and get that image at the servlet. I have written the code as

```
  <form action="servlet" method="get">
     <input type="image" name="somename" src="img/xyz.jpg"> //passed image as a input
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

How can I get image into the servlet?

Comment: Input type="image" displays an image on the submit button to submit the form. It does not submit the image itself - the image is just for aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value). What you are trying to achieve is not possible it seems.

If it is an image you are trying to submit to a server, what you need is `<input type='file' ... />`. Please clarify if it is otherwise..