# Click on image in triggers form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and on clicking the image submit form is triggered by default. I am not understanding why click is triggering form submit. Can someone please guide on this?

```
<form name="test1" action="er" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
<input type="text" id="du" name="du" value="74491" onkeyup="showButton()">
<input type="image" src="../images/save-icon.png" width="20" height="20" ></form>
```

Comment: there is probably a piece of JavaScript that is being called that you are not including here...

Comment: its a functionality..got it from he answers below. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. According to the [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image):

> input elements of type image are used to create graphical submit
>   buttons, i.e. submit buttons that take the form of an image rather
>   than text.

Comment: Indeed, the browser will also send x and y parameters giving the coordinates of the image that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

An input type="image" only defines that image as the submit button. For more [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value)

Answer (score 1):

Please use `<img src=''>`

instead of `<input type='image'>`.

Because input type image fires a default submit action! Otherwise here is a sample script that stops form submitting whenever you click a image input.

Hope my code will help you!

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  const path=e.path;
  for(let i=0;i<path.length-4;i++){
    if(path[i].tagName=="INPUT"&&path[i].type=="image"){
      var form=path[i].parentNode;
      while(form.tagName!="FORM") form=form.parentNode;
      
      let currentSubmitAttr=form.getAttribute("onsubmit");
      
      form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return false;");
      setTimeout(function(){
        form.setAttribute("onsubmit", currentSubmitAttr);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="du">
  <br><br>
  <input type='image' src='https://dummyimage.com/300x250/000/fff'>
</form>
```

Comment: You are welcome, anything else that I can help you at ?